# Looking for information or spec sheet on an old PROM/EPROM chip

Tags: identification

A week or so ago I received in the mail a lot of Game Boy prototypes.  The seller threw in a "bonus" which happened to be a small box containing the following E/PROM chips, which are not for Game Boy games.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, `HN27256G-25` is imprinted on these chips.  I've searched the internet but I can't find any information on them regarding size or read speed.

For more details on these chips, "One - on - One" was a Nintendo game that was released in 1988.  The original game was 128k in size and, I've been told, was small enough to fit on one typical development EPROM, so four wouldn't have been needed.  I'm curious why this game is on 4x chips rather than just one and the dates are also later than the final release, leaving me to speculate that that this is either an updated version of the software, or this was work on a port of the game to a new system or, possibly, to an arcade cabinet.  I wonder if this is specifically for an arcade version because "Rare Coin-It, Inc." was company that also specialized in porting arcade games to household console systems and vice-versa.

My end goal/hope is to get the details on these chips so that I can properly get the data dumped but so far I've had no luck finding information on these old chips.  Any information would be helpful.  Thank you guys.

Comment: Try Google for `27256 eprom`

Comment: 27256 is a 32k x 8 UV-EPROM, so four of them is exactly right for a 128-kB program.

Comment: Reading should be easy. Programming needs careful ramp-up and ramp-down of 50 volt, to enable the electron tunneling.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: Where are you getting your information? Even the very first UV-EPROMS (1702) didn't need that much voltage, and everything from the 2708 on was perfectly happy with a Vpp of +12V, with all switching handled on-chip.

Answer (score 2):

> My end goal/hope is to get the details on these chips so that I can properly get the data dumped

You do not need details for the EEPROM, you need programmer which would have this chip in the list of supported devices. This programmer will read data from these chips for you.

But if you are going to design your own circuit to read these chips (which I guess will be harder than locating programmer device), you can refer [here](http://www.ezoflash.com/datasheets/eprom/Hitachi/HN27256G.pdf) or any other datasheet site. HN is Hitachi version of standard 27256 UV-erasable PROMs.

Comment: You state "This programmer will read data from these chips for you." but the only link I see on your post is to the datasheet.  You have a link to a programmer/reader?

Comment: Programmer is a device, you install chip into it, and press some buttons on PC programmer is connected to, and software creates file with data contents of the chip. There're a lot of programmer devices available on the market from very expensive like one you may find on Digikey to cheap from China. Might be the best option for you is to go to nearest technical university if they have electronics/computer science faculty they most probably have what you need, and will be happy to help you in order to touch the history :)

Comment: That's as good an idea as any.  I use to work in embedded systems, but as a programmer.  So, I dabbled in the hardware side, but only as I needed to.  I still have colleague/friends who might be able to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This brings back memories.  These are EPROMs which were very common in embedded systems years ago. These look like the ceramic DIP packages that had a little window on the top, allowing them to be erased by UV light.  The -25 suffix indicates the access time: 250ns address-to-data or output enable-to-data.

Here's a link to a data sheet: [Intel 27256](http://datasheet.octopart.com/D27256-2-Intel-datasheet-17852618.pdf)